# How can I make Unity always show Filter Results?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 12.04

I want Filter Results in Unity to always show. How is that possible? I use Ubuntu 12.04. See the screenshot:

[image: filter result show]

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible in Unity. Your best bet is to report a bug about it or to suggest it on the [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com) site.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems to keep always showing left Filter menu, but only in Unity 2D mode.